# Codeigniter Injecting WHERE clause into existing query pulled from Model

Tags: codeigniter, model, controller, codeigniter-4

Here's my dilemma: I need to use the values of `$this->request->uri->getSegments()` as `WHERE` clauses in my website's queries. I understand `$this->request->uri->getSegments()` can only be accessed in the Controller, so if I am calling my query in the Controller from the Model ie.

Controller:

```
$brand = $this->request->uri->getSegment(1);

$model = new ShopModel();
data ['shop'] = $model->products()
```

Model:

```
    public function products()
    {
        $query = $this  ->table('shop')
                        ->select('brand_name, brand_name_slug, count(*) as brand_name_total')
                        ->join('(SELECT sku, MIN(sale_price) as sale_price FROM shop GROUP BY sku) as min', 'shop.sku = min.sku and shop.sale_price = min.sale_price')
                        ->where('availability', 'in stock')
                        ->where('shop.sku !=', '')
                        ->groupBy('brand_name')
                        ->orderBy('brand_name')
                        ->findAll();

        return $query;
    }
```

Is there a way for me to inject `->where('brand', $brand)` clause into `$model->products()` in the Controller?

Note: I've already trialled the idea of building all my queries IN the Controller (line by line) and adding the `WHERE` statement in order, however I kept getting bugs and this would be a 'tidier' solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pass the variable as a parameter in the function when calling it like any other function. ([Reference](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/tutorial/news_section.html#display-the-news))
**Controller**

```
$brand = $this->request->uri->getSegment(1);

$model = new ShopModel();
data ['shop'] = $model->products($brand); // pass the variable
```

**Model**

```
public function products($brand){ // get the variable value 

    $query = $this  ->table('shop')
                    ->select('brand_name, brand_name_slug, count(*) as brand_name_total')
                    ->join('(SELECT sku, MIN(sale_price) as sale_price FROM shop GROUP BY sku) as min', 'shop.sku = min.sku and shop.sale_price = min.sale_price')
                    ->where('availability', 'in stock')
                    ->where('shop.sku !=', '')
                    ->where('brand', $brand) // use it in where clause
                    ->groupBy('brand_name')
                    ->orderBy('brand_name')
                    ->findAll();

    return $query;
}
```

### **Edit**

If you want to send `multiple parameters`, you can either send them one by one or in an `array`, then in your `model`, you can check if the variable is defined or not, like so

By `multiple parameters` -

**Controller**

```
$brand = $this->request->uri->getSegment(1);
$xyz   = 'value';  // make sure to use key same as table column
$abc   = 'some-value';
$pqr   = 'some-other-value';

$model = new ShopModel();
data ['shop'] = $model->products($brand, $xyz, $abc, $pqr); // pass multiple variables
```

**Model**

```
public function products($brand = false, $xyz = false, $abc = false, $pqr = false){ // get variables value and give false default value

    $builder = $db->table('shop');

    $builder->select('brand_name, brand_name_slug, count(*) as brand_name_total');
    $builder->join('(SELECT sku, MIN(sale_price) as sale_price FROM shop GROUP BY sku) as min', 'shop.sku = min.sku and shop.sale_price = min.sale_price');
    $builder->where('availability', 'in stock');
    $builder->where('shop.sku !=', '');

    if($brand){ // if value is not false
        $builder->where('brand', $brand); // use it in where clause
    }
    if($xyz){ 
        $builder->where('xyz', $xyz);
    }
    if($abc){
        $builder->where('abc', $abc);
    }
    if($pqr){
        $builder->where('pqr', $pqr);
    }

    $builder->groupBy('brand_name')
    $builder->orderBy('brand_name')

    $query =  $builder->findAll();

    return $query;
}
```

or as an `array`
**Controller**

```
$arr['brand'] = $this->request->uri->getSegment(1);
$arr['xyz']   = 'value';  // make sure to use key same as table column
$arr['abc']   = 'some-value';
$arr['pqr']   = 'some-other-value';

$model = new ShopModel();
$data['shop'] = $model->products($arr); // pass the $arr array as parameter
```

**Model**

```
public function products($arr){ // get values in array

    $builder = $db->table('shop');

    $builder->select('brand_name, brand_name_slug, count(*) as brand_name_total');
    $builder->join('(SELECT sku, MIN(sale_price) as sale_price FROM shop GROUP BY sku) as min', 'shop.sku = min.sku and shop.sale_price = min.sale_price');
    $builder->where('availability', 'in stock');
    $builder->where('shop.sku !=', '');

    if(!empty($arr['brand']){ // if value is not false
        $builder->where('brand', $arr['brand']); // use it in where clause
    }
    if(!empty($arr['xyz']){
        $builder->where('xyz', $arr['xyz']);
    }
    if(!empty($arr['abc']){ 
        $builder->where('abc', $arr['abc']);
    }
    if(!empty($arr['pqr']){ 
        $builder->where('pqr', $arr['pqr']);
    }

    $builder->groupBy('brand_name')
    $builder->orderBy('brand_name')

    $query =  $builder->findAll();

    return $query;
}
```

You can also use `foreach` in your `model` to prevent repetition of your code -
**Model**

```
public function products($arr){ // get values in array

    $builder = $db->table('shop');

    $builder->select('brand_name, brand_name_slug, count(*) as brand_name_total');
    $builder->join('(SELECT sku, MIN(sale_price) as sale_price FROM shop GROUP BY sku) as min', 'shop.sku = min.sku and shop.sale_price = min.sale_price');
    $builder->where('availability', 'in stock');
    $builder->where('shop.sku !=', '');

    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        if(!empty($val)){ // or if($val != "") -- if value is not false 
            $builder->where($key, $val); // use it in where clause
        }
    }        

    $builder->groupBy('brand_name')
    $builder->orderBy('brand_name')

    $query =  $builder->findAll();

    return $query;
}
```

See if this helps you.

Comment: Hehe, happens to the best of us. :)